# JQuery JSON [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON that is structured like so:

students.json (UPDATED FROM COMMENTS BELOW)

```
{
  Cindy: { age: 9, m1: 80, m2: 90, s1: 90, s2: 100 },
  Mark: { age: 12, m1: 80, m2: 90, s1: 90, s2: 100 },
  Jeff: { age: 8, m1: 90, m2: 90, s1: 90, s2: 95 },
  Ann: { age: 11, m1: 90, m2: 60, s1: 90, s2: 100 },
  Jason: { age: 5, m1: 95, m2: 30, s1: 90, s2: 185 },
  Harvey: { age: 10, m1: 100, m2: 70, s1: 90, s2: 100 },
  Mike: { age: 9, m1: 100, m2: 80, s1: 90, s2: 82 },
  Ross: { age: 9, m1: 88, m2: 90, s1: 90, s2: 100 },
};
```

In my javascript code I'm importing multiple JSON using JQuery.

```
var objects = {};
$.getJSON("object1.json", function (data) {
  objects = data;
});

var students = {};
$.getJSON("info.json", function (data) {
  students = data;
});

// .......

function function1(object) {}
function function2(object) {}

// .......

function main() {
  function1(object1);
  function2(object2);
}
```

When I inspect the imported object students, I get:

```
[object Object]:{
"Cindy"   : {"age": 9,     "m1":80,  "m2":90, "s1":90 , "s2":100},
"Mark"    : {"age": 12,    "m1":80,  "m2":90, "s1":90 , "s2":100},
"Jeff"    : {"age": 8,     "m1":90,  "m2":90, "s1":90 , "s2":95},
"Ann"     : {"age": 11,    "m1":90,  "m2":60, "s1":90 , "s2":100},
"Jason"   : {"age": 5,     "m1":95,  "m2":30, "s1":90 , "s2":185},
"Harvey"  : {"age": 10,    "m1":100, "m2":70, "s1":90 , "s2":100},
"Mike"    : {"age": 9,     "m1":100, "m2":80, "s1":90 , "s2":82},
"Ross"    : {"age": 9,     "m1":88,  "m2":90, "s1":90 , "s2":100}
}
```

It appears that this [object Object] is now a "key"?

**UPDATED:**

My original question was from the thought that this was preventing me from accessing the object, but that was not my problem. It operates as expected. I can access students.Cindy.age //9 just fine. My problem is that the getJSON happens AFTER the function call so "undefined" objects are being passed into the functions. I need the html to load first as some of the javascript functions manipulate the html page.

Comment: Have you tried `students.Cindy.age` inside `$.getJSON`?

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'` and enclose all keys in `"` as well, for instance `"age"`

Comment: What I THOUGHT was my problem, wasn't actually my problem. I still don't know how to solve it. I made the improvements, but it seems $.getJSON(.....) , which is one of many objects/data I will load, is loading after the functions that need the objects. students gets passed into the function, but it's being defined afterwards so an empty object is being passed in. SIDEBAR: I'm newer...should I start a new thread or completely reword my original question?

Answer (score 0):

you can access like the following 2 types

```
students.Cindy.age
students['Cindy']['age']
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issues with missing commas around the array properties and assign the outer object to a variable. Then you can use bracket/dot notation to access the properties. You should also fix the nested objects indentation to make your code easier to read.

Check out [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ryLmpk0s/).

```
var data = {
    "Cindy": {
        "age": 9,     
        "m1": 80,  
        "m2": 90, 
        "s1": 90, 
        "s2": 100
     },
    "Mark": {
        "age": 12,    
        "m1": 80,  
        "m2": 90, 
        "s1": 90, 
        "s2": 100
     }
}
```

Now the following accesses the data:

```
alert(data["Cindy"].age);
alert(data["Mark"].m1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues. `$.getJSON("info.json"` these are async in nature. Instead of $.getJSON, u can use `fetch` It has better support. Using fetch requests. `Promise.all` wait for the responses then you can perform the task.

```
$(function () {
  function function1(objects) {
    console.log(objects)
  }
  function function2(students) {
    console.log(students.Cindy.age)
    console.log(students.Cindy.m1)
  }
  /*
  var objects = {};
  $.getJSON("object1.json", function (data) { // these are async in nature
    objects = data;
  });
  var students = {};
  $.getJSON("info.json", function (data) { // these are async in nature
    students = data;
  });
  */
  // instead of $.getJSON, u can use `fetch` It has better support
  const promises = [fetch("object1.json").then(res => res.json()) , fetch("info.json").then(res => res.json()]
  Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    const [objects, students] = results// data is avaible here, 
    function1(objects); // do something with objects
    function2(students);// do something with students
  })


})();
```